Proving the chromatic number of this graph is $4$
I was required to prove that the following graph $G = (V, E)$ satisfies $\chi(G) = 4$:

Since $C_5 \subseteq G$ we have $\chi(G) \geq 3$. Since $G$ is connected and $\Delta(G) = 5$, Brook's theorem implies $\chi(G) \leq 5$. However, I have not been able to advance any further.
My approach was to construct sub-graphs of $G$ and derive contradictions from assuming proper colorings of $3$ and $5$ colors. I have not succeeded at this attempt. Any hint or solution is appreciated.

the first step should be to write down an explicit 4-coloring of $G$, so that you known off the bat that $\chi(G)\leq 4$. This is almost always better than applying a theorem.

I believe this is the famous Grötzsch graph.


fill out the outer ring; you need 3 colors for this, it'll look like red green red green blue.  There's only one 3-coloring after symmetry.
The inner ring has a node that sees red-green (so, must be blue), another that sees red-blue (must be green), and a third that sees green-blue (must be red).
The central cell now sees red, green, and blue, so must be a fourth color.



Thank you, that makes sense.
